# Working with ansible to create a wordpress user creater

Tags: wordpress, automation, ansible

I have my script working, and it looks something like this:

```
- name: create a test user
  shell: /usr/local/bin/wp/wp-cli.phar user create {{ item.name }} {{ item.email }} --user_pass={{ item.password }} --role={{ item.role }} --path=/var/www/wp
  with_items:
     - { name: 'testuser1', email: 'testuser1@123.com', password: 123, role: author }
     - { name: 'testuser2', email: 'testuser2@123.com', password: 123, role: author }
```

This works in creating wordpress users, but I was wondering if there was a way to take the information in `with_items` and move it to a separate file of just usernames and information?

Answer (score 0):

In a [variable file (referenced with `vars_files`)](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#variable-file-separation):

```
users:
  - name: testuser1
    email: testuser1@123.com
    password: 123
    role: author
  - name: testuser2
    email: testuser2@123.com
    password: 123
    role: author
```

then:

```
- name: create a test user
  shell: /usr/local/bin/wp/wp-cli.phar user create {{ item.name }} {{ item.email }} --user_pass={{ item.password }} --role={{ item.role }} --path=/var/www/wp
  with_items: "{{users}}"
```

Comment: Ok I changed my code to look like that but then I get this error      
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "ERROR! the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'users' is undefined", "failed": true}

Comment: forgot to copy it, its in the comment now

Comment: @user2305295 If `users` is undefined you didn't load the vars file right.

Comment: Ok I have a directory sitting in the same folder as my playbook.yml called vars and then i have users.yml with the user information. And then my playbook looks like this ---

- name: Installs PHP and WP-CLI with some essential software

  hosts: all
  user: testuser

  vars_files:
    -/vars/users.yml
  roles:
    - userAdd